# Launch VScode with new.txt file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was wondering if there is a way to launch Vscode on Windows with new.txt file immediately
instead of going to file --New text file
or press CTL + N

Thanks

Comment: so you want to create a new text file whenever you open visual studio code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go inside the Settings window and look for **Startup Editor** and select **newUntitledFile**. It should be enough to have a blank page every time you launch the app.

The extension can be set later in case you want to save the new file.

[image: Options Screenshot]